# Odd tag roundup, 2011/12/14 edtion

Tags: discussion, tags

Another week, another set of weird tags:

[fast-expand](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fast-expand) - Is this maybe a subtag of SC2?  It seems like it could be a concept across multiple RTS games though.  I'm on the fence.

[economics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics) - I don't know how I feel about this one, another weird one.  Nobody following it.

[replays](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replays) - Another odd cross-game tag.  Nobody's following this one either.

[theory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory) - Is this "I have a theory about something" in which case it's probably off topic, or "let's talk about the theory behind a game" where it could be better suited for gamedev, or "game mechanics" which doesn't really seem like it could be a meaningful cross-game subdivision of game questions.

[guide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guide) - Aren't most questions asking for a guide/strategy/walkthrough of some sort?

I don't mind manually retagging some/all of these questions if we decide they're bad tags, just looking for input as I'm not 100% convinced these are all terrible.  There's no unilateral consensus on tagging, so I'm just taking notes and hoping for input before acting.

Comment: I'd probably murder them all.

Comment: I nuked black-ops-zombies since that one was the one I felt the most sure about.

Comment: basics also bit it, it was only on 4 questions from one day and the same person.  I feel like I'm making hostage threats.  IF MY DEMANDS ARE NOT MET, I WILL MURDER ONE TAG AN HOUR UNTIL THEY ARE.

Comment: What's wrong with `theory`?  [Don't be afraid to use the Science](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/dont-be-afraid-to-use-the-science/)!

Comment: Don't have any problem with theory (narrowly defined) as a topic, not sure it makes sense as a tag :)

Comment: fast-expand could apply to more than just SC2, but at present there isn't another RTS that it could apply to except maybe supreme commander, but that's not recent.